# What statistical test to use if analyzing the effect of brands of Soda on their phosphorus content?

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, t-test

As explained in the title, I was wondering what kind of statistical test one should use to analyze the phosphorus content of different brands to see if there is a meaningful statistical difference between those brands.

Is "soda brand" a categorical variable? I have tried to do research and have seen that ANOVA tests should be used when the independent variable is categorical, the dependent variable is continuous (in this case, phosphorus content, measured in multiple trials) and the data satisfies some other assumptions such as normal distribution, but I am not sure what type of variable a type of soda brand is.

Comment: A response like "phosphorus content" would have me considering suitable models for continuous proportions (perhaps beta regression for example); I'd anticipate likely right skew and heteroskedasticity. Given that phosphorus is likely to always be a very small proportion, modelling (say) logs might work reasonably well (with ordinary ANOVA), as might a gamma GLM

Answer (score 2):

Yes, without any further information, I would consider soda brand a categorical variable.  If you have Pepsi, Coke, and Dr. Pepper, there is no meaningful quantitative relationship or order.

Phosphorus content is likely continuous, and so you are correct that ANOVA is potentially appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you comment on how the ANOVA test would compare with a t-test in this case, if there are more than two different brands?

Comment: A t-test is just a special case of an ANOVA, to be used when there are only two levels of your dependent variable (Coke vs Pepsi).  If there are three or more levels (Coke, Pepsi, Dr. Pepper, etc), then use an ANOVA.  (Note that, after the ANOVA, you may use post hoc t-tests to test differences between two specific brands that you are interested in.)

Comment: Alright, thank you. So there is absolutely no difference between an ANOVA test and a t-test when there are two levels of the independent variable? Also, I was wondering when you would want to use multiple t-tests instead of an ANOVA test. When would that happen? I seem to understand that multiple t-tests increase the type I error, but are there any benefits to it?

Comment: When there are two levels of the independent variable (my previous comment mistakenly said dependent), it is called a t-test.  An ANOVA is a generalization to more than two levels.  You wouldn't talk about an ANOVA with two levels, but if you did, it would be the same as a t-test.

Comment: You would report an omnibus F-test from the ANOVA to say whether there was any difference in phosphorus content between soda brands.  But this wouldn't tell you whether Coke had extremely high phosphorus and the other two were average, or if it was Dr. Pepper that was much higher than the other two, for instance.  This is where multiple t-tests would be helpful, for things like pairwise comparisons.  You are correct that would increase type I error, but after an ANOVA, you can perform post hoc contrast t-tests and control alpha for multiple comparisons.